# parse.com update data android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an object at parse.com in the class `Grillen` with data.

Now I want to make it such that if I click a button it adds to the row with the same name as selected in a spinner, and it updates the columns `Betrag` and `Rechnung`. I tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
 public void createRechnung(View v) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Grillen")
    // Retrieve the object by id
    query.getInBackground(String.valueOf(mNameInput), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject Grillen, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Grillen.put("Betrag", mBetragInput);
                Grillen.put("Rechnung", false);
                Grillen.saveInBackground();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: in your saveInBackground add a save callback and check for exceptions or error in the callback

Comment: do you have some code for me i dont understand how i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to check what's going wrong

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Grillen");

// Retrieve the object by id
query.getInBackground(String.valueOf(mNameInput), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(ParseObject Grillen, ParseException eg) {
        if (eg == null) {
            Grillen.put("Betrag", mBetragInput);
            Grillen.put("Rechnung", false);
            Grillen.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                       //success, saved!
                       Log.d("MyApp", "Successfully saved!");
                    } else {
                       //fail to save!
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else {
            //fail to get!!
            eg.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

If you successfully save, then your exception is null, if it didn't you will know why via stacktrace. I suggest running this code and letting the execution flow of the app be based on whether or not the save was successful or not.

Read this: [getInBackground(String, callback)](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#getInBackground(java.lang.String,%20com.parse.GetCallback))  You must pass the objectId of the object you are trying to get, rather than the name. Make sure you are getting by ObjectID and not name as it appears you are doing. ObjectId looks like a random string and should be found in your database by looking online on Parse

Do this instead:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Grillen");
    query.whereEqualTo("name", String.valueOf(mNameInput));

    // Retrieve the object by id
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException eg) {
            if (eg == null && objects.size() > 0) {
                ParseObject Grillen = objects.get(0);
                Grillen.put("Betrag", mBetragInput);
                Grillen.put("Rechnung", false);
                Grillen.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            //success, saved!
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Successfully saved!");
                        } else {
                            //fail to save!
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else {
                //fail to get!!
                eg.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

**Note:** I have no idea what the column name is for the 'name' attribute of Grillen objects, so you might need to change this to whatever you call the name column for that object.

Comment: Android Studio says Cannot resolve method printStacktrace();  I think it wil log in the logcat right.

Comment: Typo, it should be printStackTrace()

Comment: okay i corrected that but if i test my app and klick on my button nothing happens int the logcat i dont see an error but also i dont see Succes message

Comment: 09-30 18:55:49.880  14425-14425/de.fusion_games.grillen W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: no results found for query       but i now that ther must be an Name that match the selceted name in the Spinner

Comment: You are getting by name, but the getInBackground method uses the object id to get the object, so you must use find

Comment: okay i understand what you mean but i want that you select the Name in an Spinner enter the ammount the user have to so i dont now the id of the object becouse it is a random string

Comment: added my update. use findInBackground and not getInBackground

Comment: added new answer with some progress and new problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have get the `Spinner` to work for the name but not the `EditText`

here is some part of the codes

```
public class RechnungActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText mBetragInput;
    private Spinner mNameInput;
    private String mName;
    private String mBetrag;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rechnung);
        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Grillen.class);

        mBetragInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Sonstiges);
        mNameInput = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        mName = mNameInput.getSelectedItem().toString();
        mBetrag = mBetragInput.getText().toString();
    }

    public void createRechnung(View v) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Grillen");
        query.whereEqualTo("name", mName);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException eg) {
                if (eg == null && objects.size() > 0) {
                    mBetrag = mBetragInput.getText().toString();
                    ParseObject Grillen = objects.get(0);
                    Grillen.put("Betrag", mBetrag);
                    Grillen.put("Rechnung", true);
                    Grillen.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                //success, saved!
                                Log.d("MyApp", "Successfully saved!");
                            } else {
                                //fail to save!
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    //fail to get!!
                    eg.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```